# I have created my own package. I get the following error: "No module name *"

Tags: python-import, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have a problem I have tried to fix. I have created my own package called [ReunionLog](https://pypi.org/project/ReunionLog/) I can create my package and install it successfully (*I think*) but when trying to use the functions I get all sort of errors in another file Main.py.

I get following error for `AttributeError: module 'ReunionLog' has no attribute 'Get_Data_Name'` when i do this following code:

```py
import requests
import os
import json
import ReunionLog as RL
publicURL = "https://www.warcraftlogs.com/api/v2/client"

def main():
    jsonName = RL.Get_Data_Name(RL.Retrieve_Headers(), publicURL, code = "LfF6BzVgpraHdb1G")
    with open(".nameReport.json", mode = "w+", encoding= "utf-8") as f:
            json.dump(jsonName, f)
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ReportAbilities'` when I have this code:

```py
import requests
import os
import json
import Report as RP
import OAuth as AU

publicURL = "https://www.warcraftlogs.com/api/v2/client"

def main():
    jsonName = RP.Get_Data_Name(AU.Retrieve_Headers(), publicURL, code = "LfF6BzVgpraHdb1G")
    with open(".nameReport.json", mode = "w+", encoding= "utf-8") as f:
            json.dump(jsonName, f)
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

This is my source directory:

```
ReunionLog
├── LICENCE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
└── src
    ├── OAuth
    │   ├── Authentication.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── Report
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── ReportAbilities.py
        ├── ReportEventsDamageDone.py
        ├── ReportEventsDeath.py
        ├── ReportEventsInterrupts.py
        └── ReportNames.py
```

This is my setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name= ReunionLog
version = 0.1.3.59
author= nickgismokato
author_email= nickvillumlaursen@gmail.com
url= https://github.com/nickgismokato/ReunionLog
#packages= ['OAuth', 'Report']
license= MIT License
description= A small package to access and use WarcraftLogs API
long_description= A small package that can use the WarcraftLogs api and from there call function to retrive data fram WarcraftLogs
#install_requires=[
#    "gql-query-builder >= 0.1.7"
#]
keywords= python, WarcraftLogs-API, package
classifiers=
    Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha
    Intended Audience :: End Users/Desktop
    Intended Audience :: Other Audience
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Operating System :: OS Independent

[options]
zip_safe = False
packages = find:
include_package_data = True
python_requires = >= 3.8
package_dir =
    =src

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

My pyproject follow standard convention. My `__init__.py` in report is on the following form:

```py
import ReportAbilities.
import ReportEventsDamageDone
import ReportEventsDeath
import ReportEventsInterrupts
import ReportNames

"""
#Abilities
from .ReportAbilities import Get_AbilityList
from .ReportAbilities import Get_Data_Ability
#Damage Done
from .ReportEventsDamageDone import Get_Data_EventDamageDone
#Death
from .ReportEventsDeath import Get_Data_EventDeath
#Interrupts
from .ReportEventsInterrupts import Get_Data_EventInterrupts

#Names
from .ReportNames import Get_Data_Name
from .ReportNames import Get_NameList
"""
```

There has been some trial and error as you can see.

My `__init__.py` in OAuth is as follows:

```py
#import Authentication
from Authentication.Retrive_headers import Retrieve_Headers
```

My .py files just have some imports and have some functions. I just can't seem to solve this problem. I hope it's just a case of my being an idiot.

Tried to change my init files and also went from setup.py to pyproject.toml to see if that solved my problem.

## EDIT

I followed the advice of both @sinoroc and @USR . I still get an error. My new dic tree is:

```
.
├── LICENCE
├── README.md
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
└── src
    ├── ReunionLog
    │   ├── OAuth
    │   │   └── Authentication.py
    │   └── Report
    │       ├── ReportAbilities.py
    │       ├── ReportEventsDamageDone.py
    │       ├── ReportEventsDeath.py
    │       ├── ReportEventsInterrupts.py
    │       └── ReportNames.py
    └── __init__.py
```

where my `__init__.py` has the following code:

```py
from ReunionLog.OAuth.Authentication import Retrieve_Headers
from ReunionLog.Report.ReportAbilities import Get_AbilityList
from ReunionLog.Report.ReportAbilities import Get_Data_Ability
from ReunionLog.Report.ReportEventsDamageDone import Get_Data_EventDamageDone
from ReunionLog.Report.ReportEventsDeath import Get_Data_EventDeath
from ReunionLog.Report.ReportEventsInterrupts import Get_Data_EventInterrupts
from ReunionLog.Report.ReportNames import Get_Data_Name
from ReunionLog.Report.ReportNames import Get_NameList
```

The full error I get is as follow:

```
nickgismokato@Nick-PC:/mnt/c/Users/nicka/OneDrive/BjLog$ python3 Main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "Main.py", line 28, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "Main.py", line 13, in main
    jsonName = RL.Get_Data_Name(RL.Retrieve_Headers(), publicURL, code = "LfF6BzVgpraHdb1G")
AttributeError: module 'ReunionLog' has no attribute 'Get_Data_Name'
```

This is for the file `Main.py` where the code is:

```py
import requests
import os
import json
import ReunionLog as RL

publicURL = "https://www.warcraftlogs.com/api/v2/client"

def main():
    jsonName = RL.Get_Data_Name(RL.Retrieve_Headers(), publicURL, code = "LfF6BzVgpraHdb1G")
    with open(".nameReport.json", mode = "w+", encoding= "utf-8") as f:
            json.dump(jsonName, f)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

## EDIT 2 (Answer)

The answer can be found in the comments made by @sinoroc My new dic tree is:

```
.
├── LICENCE
├── README.md
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
└── src
    └── ReunionLog
        ├── OAuth
        │   ├── Authentication.py
        │   └── __init__.py
        ├── Report
        │   ├── ReportAbilities.py
        │   ├── ReportEventsDamageDone.py
        │   ├── ReportEventsDeath.py
        │   ├── ReportEventsInterrupts.py
        │   ├── ReportNames.py
        │   └── __init__.py
        └── __init__.py
```

My `__init__.py` in `Report` and `OAuth` is empty and my `__init__.py` in `ReunionLog` is as described in EDIT

Comment: Seems to me like you should move the directories `src/OAuth` and `src/Report` to `src/ReunionLog/Oauth` and `src/ReunionLog/Report`. So that your one and only top-level import package is `ReunionLog`. Once this is done make sure to make all your imports absolute and starting with `ReunionLog` (your top-level import package), for example `from ReunionLog.OAuth.Authentication import RetrieveHeader`. -- Aside: as far as I know, the convention in Python is to use "snake case" for file and directory names, so I would recommend `src/reunion_log/report/report_names.py`.

Comment: So it didn't help if i understood you correctly. Haven't tried the snake case. (*I normally develop in ```C#```*). You can check my edit to see if i did it correctly.

Comment: The snake case is not important, just a convention. -- Every directory that is meant to be an importable package has to contain a `__init__.py` file (it is a must!). `src` is not an importable package (you do not want to `import src`) so it does not need a `__init__.py` file (`src/__init__.py` should be deleted). But you need one package initializer in every single directory below `src`, for example: `src/ReunionLog/__init__.py`, `src/ReunionLog/OAuth/__init__.py`, and so on. `__init__.py` files can be totally empty files (0 bytes), they often are, but they have to be there.

Comment: So should i add a zero case ```__init__.py``` in ```OAuth``` and ```Report```? I.e an ```__init__.py``` that are empty.

Comment: Yes, you should add those.

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks so much. Now i get som funny warnings but it does give correct output and that warning has something to do with my linux sub system. But agian Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not necessarily need to import all the other submodules in your `__init__.py`. second of all, there is a little "." in line 1 of your `__init__.py` right here: `import ReportAbilities.`.
Also, it would be quite helpful to have the entire error messages (wich file causes the error, and in what line is it caused)

Comment: There were indeed a "." I didn't intend on. I did try to change it but without succes. I have made an edit with full error code after i implemented @sinoroc idea.